# Partial Sum Formula of Yet Another Harmonic Series...

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers

I've got another harmonic series question.

What is the partial sum of the following:

$$\sum_{p=2}^n-\frac{2p^{3-2m}H_p}{{(ap^2-1)}^2}+\frac{2(1-m)p^3H_p}{{(ap^2-1)}^2}+\frac{2mpH_p}{{(ap^2-1)}^2}$$

where $$[a,m] \in \Bbb R$$
I am familiar with two double sums (across two variables) which yield this sum, they are not helpful. I can add them here if required.